# Converting cURL command to R GET request

Tags: r, curl, get, httr, rcurl

Does anybody know how to convert more complex cURL commands into httr:GET() requests.  The issue I am having is that the API only requires a key in the form of a username <YOUR_API_KEY> but does not require any password.

```
$ curl https://api.goclimate.com/v1/flight_footprint \
  -u YOUR_API_KEY: \
  -d 'segments[0][origin]=ARN' \
  -d 'segments[0][destination]=BCN' \
  -d 'segments[1][origin]=BCN' \
  -d 'segments[1][destination]=ARN' \
  -d 'cabin_class=economy' \
  -d 'currencies[]=SEK' \
  -d 'currencies[]=USD' \
  -G
```

Perhaps another package like Rcurl might be more appropriate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, when you include the ":" with nothing after it, you are specifying a password as the empty string. So using `httr` that would be like

```
GET("https://api.goclimate.com/v1/flight_footprint",
    authenticate("YOUR_API_KEY",""),
    query=list(
        "segments[0][origin]"="ARN",
        "segments[0][destination]"="BCN",
        "segments[1][origin]"="BCN",
        "segments[1][destination]"="ARN",
        "cabin_class"="ecomony",
        "currencies[0]"="SEK",
        "currencies[1]"="USD"))
```

Expanding the indexes of the paramters is kind of messy, you can write a helper function

```
query_expand <- function(x) {
  expd <- function(name, value) {
    do.call("c", unname(Map(function(name, value) {
      if(is.list(value) && !is.null(names(value))) {
        xx <- expd(paste0("[", names(value), "]"), value)
        setNames(xx, paste0(name, names(xx)))
      } else if(is.list(value)) {
        xx <- expd(paste0("[",seq_along(value)-1,"]"), value)
        setNames(xx, paste0(name, names(xx)))
      } else if (length(value)>1) {
        setNames(as.list(value), paste0(name, "[", seq_along(value)-1,"]"))
      } else {
        setNames(list(value), name)
      }}, name, value)))
  }
  expd(names(x), x)
}
```

Then if you have your data nearly in an object

```
params <- list("segments" = list(
    list(origin="ARN", destination="BCN"),
    list(origin="BCN", destination=c("ARN"))
  ),
  "cabin_class" = "ecomony",
  "currencies" = c("SEK","USD"))
```

You could just use

```
GET("https://api.goclimate.com/v1/flight_footprint",
    authenticate("YOUR_API_KEY",""),
    query = query_expand(params))
```

Comment: I am still getting a 400 error, and i tested using regular cURL command, which works fine. There is something not right with the query syntax and I can't figure that part out.